# IIS stops responding for a single page sometimes not always

Tags: iis-7

I have a web application that works fine for all of its pages, but I have a page that IIS stops responding when I request it < load for ever in FF and from my iPad Safari said that the web server stop responding >

When I reset IIS it works fine for a while and then I face the same problem again.

I do nothing critical nor complicated in this page load it is all about http request and it works fine in local host very fine also!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please answer some of these and maybe I'll be able to help out.
Anything showing up in the logs? Do you have a separate pool for that website? If you recycle the pool is that enough to get that page working again? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a separate pool for that website? Yes i have <br> If you recycle the pool is that enough to get that page working again? yes this happened before your Q i reset iis but now i just recycle the pool thanks for your replay and who can i face this problem?

Comment: i found the solution here

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true

when i make that the pool will recycle after 1 or 2 requests this solve the problem at all !

thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution here

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true

when i make that the pool will recycle after 1 or 2 requests this solve the problem at all !

thanks